# uploading raw data to a firebase storage bucket in a Google Cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function and I'm trying to save some data into Firebase storage. I'm using the `firebase-admin` package to interact with Firebase.

I'm reading through the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) and it seems to have clear instructions on how to upload files if the file is on your local computer.

```
// Uploads a local file to the bucket
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
    // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
    // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  },
});
```

In my case through, I have a Google Cloud Function which will be fed some data in the postbody and I want to save that data over to the Firebase bucket.

How do I do this? The upload method only seems to specify a filepath and doesn't have a data parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [save](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) method:

```js
storage
  .bucket('gs://myapp.appspot.com')
  .file('dest/path/in/bucket')
  .save('This will get stored in my storage bucket.', {
    gzip: true,
    contentType: 'text/plain'
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

The API docs for [Bucket.upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#upload) state that it's just a wrapper around [File.createWriteStream()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createWriteStream).  This method will create a WritableStream that you can use upload data that's already in memory.  You will deal with this stream just like you would any other stream in Node.  There is sample code in the API docs.

Comment: I honestly still don't understand how you're supposed to do it without saving the file to disk, what will we pass as a parameter there? 

@Diskdrive did you manage to do it?